# Continuity under various topologies for positive linear functionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, positivity, continuity, locally-convex-spaces

It is known that if $\mathcal A$ is a unital $\mathbb C$-$*$-algebra and $A$ is a unital subalgebra closed under $*$, and if $f : A \to \mathbb C$ is linear, then $f$ is positive if and only if $f$ is continuous and $\|f\| = f(1)$.

> Can similar statements be produced for a larger class of topological algebras? I am particularly interested in the case when $\mathcal A$ is the algebra $C_b (X)$ of bounded continuous functions on some Hausdorff topological space $X$, endowed with some of the the usual interesting topologies given by modes of convergence (compact convergence, strict topology etc.).

Comment: It seems that there is no general theory even for fairly decent classes of topological algebras as suggest recent proofs for particular cases; see, for example, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X15006307

Comment: The question makes no sense. $f$ is continuous implies $f$ is positive?

Comment: @NikWeaver: On unital $\mathbb C$-$*$-algebras yes, with the condition $\| f \| = f(1)$ that you may have involuntarily skipped. See the bibliography referenced on the [relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_linear_functional#Positive_linear_functionals_(C*-algebras)). Intuitively, non-rigorously, $f$ is an "integral", therefore it is associated to a positive measure, therefore it must be positive. How do we deal with the downvote now?

Comment: If $f$ is linear and continuous then so is $-f$.

Comment: @NikWeaver: Mind slip, obviously: I had interchanged the words "positive" and "continuous". Why the need to downvote such minor mistakes?

Comment: $C_b(X)$ is again a unital C*-algebra. Hence also in this case you get the equivalence between positivity and continuity plus $\|f\|=f(1)$. The relevant topology here is the norm topology. The topology of compact convegence and the strict topology are strictly coarser when $X$ is not compact. I don't know how to find positive functionals that are not continuous wrt the strict topology, but the evaluation maps at points $x\in\beta X$ (or equivalently the characters of $C_b(X)$) should be good candidates.

Comment: I suppose, ${\mathbb C}$-$*$-algebra must be $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: Yes, that is right.